# allowing java script using noscript in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, noscript

When I open a website, noscript blocks running the java script associated with the website. On the Options menu of NoScript I can find the blocked scripts and I can temporarily or permanently allow them. There are lots of scripts that needs to be allowed when you click on the Options button.

Basically I want to avoid selecting the option "Temporarily allow all" and instead only select the one which is related to my event.

Example: I go to a website abcd.com and there I allow to run the java script allow.com through NoScripts. Now on the website, there is a button which I want to click, but this button is also associated with a java script which I dont know from the list of scripts available for me as an option to allow temporarily or permanently.
The question is how do you know which script is associated with the button? Can I see this information with "WebDeveloper" tool in Firefox, that the script named "xyz" has been blocked because I have clicked on a particular link/button on the webpage?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. Try SuperUser.

Comment: okay, did it http://superuser.com/questions/934068/how-to-know-which-java-script-is-interfaced-with-a-particular-link-or-a-button-o